# How to set a DDNS in Traefik host?

Tags: docker, server, traefik

I am new in Traefik and I am using that to make the reverse proxy for my docker images, and I want to use my local computer like a server that could be accessed externally. 
Here is what I did:

1. I create a DDNS pointing to my external ip in No-Ip: 
   **Host-name:** *myhost.ddns.net* 
   **Target/ip:** *my-external-ip* 
   **Type**: *A*
2. I want to use Traefik, so I want to expose the http default port (80) and https default port (443), so I made the port-forward in my router:
   [image: https port-forward]

[image: http port-forward]

Doing that, I expect that http or https requests is being redirect to my internal host, that is the one which is the server of my application

3. Create the **docker-compose.yml** and **traefik.yml** files:

docker-compose.yml:

```
   version: '3.7'
    
    services:
      traefik:
        image: traefik:v2.0.1
        container_name: traefik
        restart: unless-stopped
        security_opt:
          - no-new-privileges:true
        networks:
          - external
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
        volumes:
          - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
          - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
          - ./acme.json:/acme.json
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.myhost.ddns.net`)"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=*user:password*
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.myhost.ddns.net`)"
          # - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
          - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"

*another-services-configs...*

networks:
  external:
    external: true
```

traefik.yml:

```
api:
  dashboard: true

# Writing Logs to a File, in JSON
log:
  level: DEBUG
  filePath: "log-file.log"
  format: json

# Configuring a buffer of 100 lines
accessLog:
  filePath: "log-access.log"
  bufferingSize: 100  

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: my-email@hotmail.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

Finally, when I run `docker-compose up -d` , the application goes on, but I can not acess the traefik dashboard when I try to access **traefik.myhost.ddns.net** in the browser. The error message is that could not be found any web site with that host. 
But, if I change the Host-name in the label to `- traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host('traefik.localhost')"` , I can access the traefik dashboard typing **traefik.localhost** in the browser.

The question is, how can I use my ddns in the Host label to be able to access my traefik server externally?